# Android Studio não exerga aparelho do Genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

Instalei o Android Studio o Genymotion, criei um aparelho virtual no Genymotion, coloquei para rodar o aparelho virtual mas o Android Studio na hora de executar ele não localiza o aparelho. Instalei o plugin do Genymotion no Android Studio mas mesmo assim não funciona. Estou usando o Windows 10.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261474/android-studio-doesnt-see-genymotion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver esse problema.

No genymotion vai em `Settings/ADB` (provavelmente vai está como default), coloque o caminho do `sdk`

Answer (score 0):

Tenho o mesmo problema, a maneira de contornar é abres o emulador, no android studio fazes build/build apk, depois de feita carregas em show no explorer, e depois é só arrastares o ficheiro para dentro do emulador.
Isto não é bem uma grande solução mas ao menos resolve para já o teu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o colega respondeu, basta ir no genymotion em settings/ADB, marcar a opção (Use custom Android SDK Tools) e selecionar o caminho (C:/Users/seu_usuario/AppData/Local/Android/sdk).